# How can I do UI testing using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

What are the requirements for User Interface testing using Selenium IDE? 
I have to test a login page. Do I have to write a UI map file for this? 
How can I implement the file in the IDE?

Comment: There are many tutorials.  For example: [this one](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp) straight from SeleniumHQ

Comment: You should start with the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin , so only requirement is having a compatible version of firefox , and you could use the tutorials given by  "sircapsalot"

Additional Notes -

1)As far as I know UI Map is a  part of Coded UI and not a concern in Selenium IDE .

2)From personal experience I think Using Selenium Web driver over Selenium IDE would be a good choice for having maintainable robust test framework in long term